# The repeat command syntax in zsh

Tags: zsh, syntax

I'm beginning with zsh and I use [this manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Complex-Commands).

The syntax for repeat is presented as:

> repeat *word* do *list* done

However I've noticed that:

```
repeat 5 echo ok
```

also works fine.

Still, this omission is not legit here:

```
~ % f() { for a ; do echo $a; }
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

So the question is, is that a hole bug in the code or a valid omission? Can it be relied on? I see it's popular in code samples.

I searched for `repeat` in zsh's man, but nothing's there apparently. What's the proper zsh documentation anyhow?

Comment: `f () {for a; echo $a}` is fine, though.

Comment: Which doesn't make it more simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
repeat word do list done
```

Is indeed the syntax for repeat, try reading [section 6.4 - Alternate Forms For Complex Commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-alternate-forms-for-complex-commands) now, noting the warning:

> These are non-standard and are likely not to be obvious even to
>   seasoned shell programmers.

> ```
> repeat word sublist
> ```
>
> This is a short form of repeat.